# Listview of backendless directories

Tags: android, listview, backendless

I'm using backendless and I'm trying to display my directories in a listview. I'm using Android Studio.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Backendless.setUrl(Defaults.SERVER_URL);
        Backendless.initApp(this, Defaults.APPLICATION_ID, Defaults.SECRET_KEY, Defaults.VERSION);



        Backendless.Files.listing("/Uploads", "*docs", true, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<FileInfo>>() {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<FileInfo> fileInfoBackendlessCollection) {
                Iterator<FileInfo> filesIterator = fileInfoBackendlessCollection.getCurrentPage().iterator();
                while (filesIterator.hasNext()) {
                    FileInfo file = filesIterator.next();
                    String URL = file.getURL();
                    String publicURL = file.getPublicUrl();
                    Date createdOn = new Date(file.getCreatedOn());
                    String name = file.getName();

                    String[] info = {URL, publicURL, name};
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getListView().getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, info);
                    getListView().setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

It has no error but the app doesn't open. Can anyone help me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the start for fixing your problem:

```
        @Override
        public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<FileInfo> fileInfoBackendlessCollection) {

            // create a list for your data
            List<String> infoList = new ArrayList<>();

            Iterator<FileInfo> filesIterator = fileInfoBackendlessCollection.getCurrentPage().iterator();
            while (filesIterator.hasNext()) {
                FileInfo file = filesIterator.next();
                String URL = file.getURL();
                String publicURL = file.getPublicUrl();
                Date createdOn = new Date(file.getCreatedOn());
                String name = file.getName();

                // put everything into one string temporarily
                // String[] info = {URL, publicURL, name};
                String info = URL + " " + publicURL + " " + name;
                infoList.add(info);
            }

            // loop through ALL your data before creating/assigning adapter
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getListView().getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, infoList);
            getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Now your adapter is going to get a little more complicated, because you will not want to have everything on one line.  You will need to create a layout for your list item. Then you need to use either `SimpleAdapter` or create a custom class extending `BaseAdapter` and use that to display your data.

Comment: It's still crashes sir. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: If you have a stack trace in the logcat, please post that to help the community figure out what's really wrong.

Comment: This is in my logcat. I cant show all the errors in my logcat because its too long.

Comment: 5100-5100/com.example.francis.classdroidapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.francis.classdroidapp/com.example.francis.classdroidapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: That message sounds pretty straightforward to me.  You need a `ListView` with `android:id="@android:id/list"` in your activity_main.xml

Comment: Thank you kris larson. My app doesn't crash anymore. But this time the it's not showing anything. It's just a blank when i open it. It's like the list view is not getting any data. This is what the logcat shows

Comment: This is the first 2 lines in my logcat:

D/AbsListView: checkAbsListViewlLogProperty get invalid command.

Comment: Could not find method weborb.management.messaging.DestinationMessageCountWatcher.getInstance, referenced from method weborb.v3types.core.DestinationManager.addDestination.

Comment: VFY: unable to resolve static method 20185: Lweborb/management/messaging/DestinationMessageCountWatcher;.getInstance ()Lweborb/management/messaging/DestinationMessageCountWatcher;